# zsh keybinding: insert-last-word

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts

In `zsh`, I have <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> bound to `insert-last-word`

When I am listing through the last command parameters by repeatedly pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>, sometimes I press one too many and I need to go one back.

What keybinding is used to go back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just `undo`, bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> in `emacs` mode by default (note that `insert-last-word` is also bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd>).

After `undo`ing though, if you invoke `insert-last-word` again, you'll be back to the beginning, you can't just alternate pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> to go back and forth in the history.

For that, you'd need to define a separate widget that invokes the `insert-last-word` widget with `1` as argument (see `info zsh insert-last-word` for details).

For instance, bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>:

```
insert-last-word-forward() zle insert-last-word 1
zle -N insert-last-word-forward
bindkey '\e,' insert-last-word-forward
```

Comment: the `bind` on the last line did not work. I had to change that to `bindkey`.

Comment: @Martin, sorry, my bad. Fixed now.